# Jquery Variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a project and I am trying to use jquery to send a variable to php. This a file called test2.php that I have been using to test out the code, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong because it should be printing out the variable when you click on the button but nothing is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var something="hello";
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({ url: 'test2.php',type: "GET", data: { q : something }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['q']))
{

$q = $_GET["q"];
echo $q;
}
?>
```

Comment: AJAX executes the code in target URL in the background. It wouldn't show up or replace the contents of the page you're currently on. If you'd like to see whether the AJAX request itself was successful, go to the `Console` of your browser (by pressing `F12` on most) and view the `Network` tab.

Comment: Your JavaScript code isn't doing anything with the AJAX response, just ignoring it.  In the jQuery documentation and examples for `$.ajax()` take a look at the "success" and "error" callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks generally correct but you have to remember that an AJAX call sends the data "Asynchronously", which means when you click on the button this data is being sent to a separate instance of "test2.php" for processing. It is not reloading the current page with this new data.

The "test2.php" code you are viewing in browser is only run on the server side once when you first start up the page, and there is no 'q' in the '$_GET' variable at that time. The AJAX request *is* sending data to a separate instance of the same "test2.php" file and it *is* receiving some data back, but it is not using that information to load anything into your browser.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are many different solutions. You could use what you receive from your AJAX request to update information on the page like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test2.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { q: something},
    success: function (response) {
        // do something with 'response' here
    }
});
```

Or you could have the button instead be a simple `<a>` tag that reloads the current page in browser with information stored in '$_GET' like so:

```
<a href="test2.php?q=something">Button</a>
```

Then when your PHP code looks for 'q' it would actually find it in the $_GET variable because you reloaded the page.

Comment: `"and then never being returned to you"` - That's a bit misleading.  The results *are* being returned to his JavaScript code, that code is simply ignoring them.

Comment: @David yes that is correct, I will update my answer accordingly, thanks.